# I would like to split text in a column for a pandas dataframe based on multiple Delimiters and create new rows for each

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

Hello everyone below is my dataframe:

Below is my dataset:

```
Name      University            Subject              

John      Harvard               English, French
John      MIT                   Economics 
Alan      BU                    Data Science & Math
```

I would like to have the following output:

```
Name      University            Subject              

John      Harvard               English
John      Harvard               French
John      MIT                   Economics 
Alan      BU                    Data Science
Alan      BU                    Math
```

I have tried the code below:

```
df.drop('subject', axis=1).join(df['subject'].str.split(',', expand=True).stack().reset_index(level=1,drop=True).rename('subject'))
```

This works but only splits it according to ',' but I would also like to split it for '&'.

Please help me, I am generally new to python and am open to using all libraries like Pandas and NumPy.

I found the above solution on another Stackoverflow question, however, I do not fully understand the steps. Please explain the steps as clearly as possible.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex expression in place of just `','` to include additional characters to split on. For example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['John', 'John', 'Alan', 'Joe'], 
'University':['Harvard', 'MIT', 'BU', 'NYU'], 
'Subject':['English, French', 'Economics', 'Data Science & Math', 
'Economics and French']})

df = df.drop('Subject', axis=1).join(df['Subject'].str.split(',|&|and', expand=True).stack().reset_index(level=1,drop=True).rename('Subject'))

# remove extra white space
df['Subject'] = df['Subject'].str.strip()
df
```

```
   Name University       Subject
0  John    Harvard       English
0  John    Harvard        French
1  John        MIT     Economics
2  Alan         BU  Data Science
2  Alan         BU          Math
3   Joe        NYU     Economics
3   Joe        NYU        French
```

Comment: thank you for the response it worked quite well.

Another question is what if I have 'and' instead of '&'.

So for subject it would be Data Science and Math.

I tried using df = df.drop('Subject', axis=1).join(df['Subject'].str.split('[,&and]', expand=True).stack().reset_index(level=1,drop=True).rename('Subject'))

But this does not work.

Comment: sure. i've updated the example. for regex, `[,&]` matches anytime you have one of those characters. using `[,&and]` would match `,`, `&`, `a`, `n`, or `d`. Instead you want to match on the word `and` so that's why you should use `,|&|and`, which matches `,`, `&` or `and`.

Comment: Pythex.org is the url to a great online tool to test out regular expressions.

Comment: great. make sure to accept the solution if it is satisfactory.